# JavaFX - Bind LinkedHashMap to ComboBox

Tags: javafx, javafx-2

I have LinkedHashMap with data from database.

```
private Map<Integer, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
eg: 1, Value1
    2, Value2
    etc.
```

**Am I able to bind this LinkedHashMap with ComboBox as Observable values?**

So far, I have filled this ComboBox this code.

```
ComboBox.getItems().addAll(this.linkedHashMap.values());
```

Problem is if I need to reload values I have to clear all ComboBox values and I have to import values again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use an `ObservableMap`:

```
private Map<Integer, String> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
....

ComboBox<String> c = new ComboBox<>();
ObservableMap<Integer, String> observableMap = FXCollections.observableMap(linkedHashMap);
observableMap.addListener(new MapChangeListener<Integer, String>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(
            javafx.collections.MapChangeListener.Change<? extends Integer, ? extends String> change) {
        if(change.wasAdded()) {
            c.getItems().add(change.getValueAdded());
        } else if(change.wasRemoved()) {
            c.getItems().remove(change.getValueRemoved());
        }
    }
});
```

In order for `CombBox` to be updated automatically, add your entries to ‍`observableMap`:

```
observableMap.put(someInt, "someValue");
```